# Why does a gstreamer demuxer need a queue?

Tags: c++, video, video-streaming, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have used various gstreamer demuxers like qt, ogg and matroska, and every time i have found deadlocking/stalling issues when not using a queue after each demuxer pad.

However i can not seem to find the cause of this either in the source code or documentation. Doesnt gstreamer use one thread per pad? As such one pad being blocked wouldnt block the other too.

Comment: I don't know. But if I were to *guess*, I'd say that the (de)muxing process takes time and that can cause samples to be delayed or lost if there's no queue to hold samples when the processor can't keep up (or gets interrupted to do other stuff).

Comment: No, pads are not threaded. They are called synchronous from the streaming thread. https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/handy-elements.html?gi-language=c#queue

Comment: Ok so let's say you have a muxer name=mux demuxer name=demux demux.video_0 ! muxer.video_0 demux.audio_0 ! mux.audio_0. No queues. What could cause a deadlock in this case? Because i get it very often. And if i use queues the ram usage increases by a LOT

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the rate of the incoming stream, the demuxing process might not be fast enough.

In simple cases where the demux is done for a single pad and downstream elements are able to process the data fast enough, a queue might not be needed, but that is a very specific use case.

It also depends on the pipeline elements downstream that have their own slow processing time. This could cause latency to build up until the demux possibly can't dequeue already processed buffers.

Comment: Wouldnt that mean that the source just stops sending until more data is needed? At least im using filesrc and not live sources so i guess that would be the case

Comment: `filesrc` will actually stop sending data if that happens. What can end up happening is this resulting in the pipeline not prerolling due to buffers not queued being in queue. This leaves the pipeline frozen.